Grid cards take height of highest element
I have a couple of cards rendered in a grid with max. 4 columns and x rows, the card's height is variable, based on the content inside the card.
Is there an easy way I can make sure that all card have the same height of the one with the highest height?
Right now, all the cards in my first row perfectly adapt as that's where my highest card is in. But my second doesn't take the desired height.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Grid</title>
  <style>
    .App {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .container {
      display: grid;
      gap: 15px;
    }

    .row {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
      gap: 15px;
    }

    .item {
      background-color: rgb(126, 136, 145);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="item">
        <p>
          This element can have a variable height based on the content placed
          on it
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>




add grid-auto-rows: 1fr to container
